# Error when getting all JSON data in my Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get data from JSON url to my ionic app , the json url shows only 10 posts per page and the total of posts is 59 (count=59),
so when I want to display all posts in my JSON in one page I use this URL:

http://tunisiebillet.com/api/get_posts/?post_type=product&count=59

my problem that when I want to GET the data on my ANGULARJS controller ,it doesn't accept more than count=54
when I want to get more than 54 posts I receive this error

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 337731
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at fromJson (ionic.bundle.js:14660)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (ionic.bundle.js:23680)
at ionic.bundle.js:23771
at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:13696)
at transformData (ionic.bundle.js:23770)
at transformResponse (ionic.bundle.js:24559)
at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
at ionic.bundle.js:29148
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
```

This is my controller :

```
.controller('MainCtrl',function($http , $scope , $sce , $ionicScrollDelegate){

$scope.recent_posts=[];
$http.get("http://tunisiebillet.com/api/get_posts/?post_type=product&count=59").then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.recent_posts=data.data.posts
    $scope.recent_posts.forEach(function(element,index,array){
        element.excerpt= element.excerpt.substr(0,100);
        element.excerpt= element.excerpt+"...Read More";
        element.excerpt=$sce.trustAsHtml(element.excerpt); 
    })

},function(err){

})

    $scope.loadMore=function(){

    }


    $scope.searchTextChanged=function(){
        $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollTop(true);
    }
```

})

Comment: Is it possible that the data is malformed near the end of the result set?

Comment: I don t think so , do you have any another solution to get all data in one json page other than "count=" ?

Comment: Does the tunisiebillet.com API support paging?

Comment: yes I can access to the second page of data for example :http://tunisiebillet.com/api/get_posts/?post_type=product&page=2

Comment: Okay! Try fetching 10 results per page until you reach 60 results. That should do it. If the last page throws an error it's likely an issue with the JSON data itself.

Comment: I got the error on the page=6 , 'Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ status: "ok", post:
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined''